# Reading json with javascript from jsp file

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

So I have a JSP file where I simply output the json code, and I'm trying to use that json in my javascript script (in another page), but it doesn't seem to work, the console says that that the returned value is undefined. If I give some "real" API URL, it works though.

This is my json_company.jsp

```
<%@page import="algo.user36.Service"%>
<%@ page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
    Service service = new Service();
    out.print(service.generatedJsonCompany());  
%>
```

This is my javascript function

```
function getData() {

$.getJSON( "json_company.jsp", function( data ) {

        console.log(data);

    });

}
```

If I go directly to json_company.jsp, it is the excepted output.

Is this a way that isn't supposed to work?

Comment: can you provide generated JSON?

Comment: callback([ {"product_description":"Blueberries 1kg","QTE":"54797.0","REVENUS":"357873.6"}, {"product_description":"Mixed Fruits 500g","QTE":"153549.0","REVENUS":"690961.5"}, {"product_description":"Nuts 500g","QTE":"184481.0","REVENUS":"872008.44"}, {"product_description":"Original 1kg","QTE":"51175.0","REVENUS":"300284.4"}, {"product_description":"Raisins 1kg","QTE":"145205.0","REVENUS":"670625.85"}, {"product_description":"Strawberries 500g","QTE":"68685.0","REVENUS":"363077.0"}]);

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the code that you have provided.

```
callback([ {"product_description":"Blueberries 1kg","QTE":"54797.0","REVENUS":"357873.6"}, {"product_description":"Mixed Fruits 500g","QTE":"153549.0","REVENUS":"690961.5"}, {"product_description":"Nuts 500g","QTE":"184481.0","REVENUS":"872008.44"}, {"product_description":"Original 1kg","QTE":"51175.0","REVENUS":"300284.4"}, {"product_description":"Raisins 1kg","QTE":"145205.0","REVENUS":"670625.85"}, {"product_description":"Strawberries 500g","QTE":"68685.0","REVENUS":"363077.0"}]);
```

You return callback function, not json itself that is typical for jsonp request. Try to predefine callback function in your javascript before call.

```
function callback(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Give it a try:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: "json_company.jsp",
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.dir(json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

And be sure to check your request in firebug\chrome console to exclude 404 code.

Comment: Same result. I just added exactly the function you provided

Comment: @yoloswag it says exactly undefined?

Comment: @lancemanfv @yoloswag is saying to have `json_company.jsp` NOT return the JSON wrapped in the `callback(...)` function. Instead, have `json_company.jsp` return JUST the JSON string. Run it through JSONLint just to make sure it is valid.